# Inkscape SVG to PSTricks Commandline

Tags: pstricks, svg, inkscape

With Inkscape I can save an .svg files to PSTricks (.tex) via the Save As dialogue.

Is there a possibility to manage this via command line? 
I only find export to latex which is no PSTricks format.

Answer (score 1):

`inkscape --export-type="tex" my_file.svg`

See also https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/Using_the_Command_Line#Via_export_options